# How to implement pipe function with arg AND ...funcs?

Tags: javascript

```
const replaceUnderscoreWithSpace = (value) => value.replace(/_/g, ' ')
const capitalize = (value) =>
    value
        .split(' ')
        .map((val) => val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1))
        .join(' ');
const appendGreeting = (value) => `Hello, ${value}!`

const pipe = (value, ...funcs) => value => funcs.reduce((value, f) => f(value), value)
```

I`m trying to implement pipe function, but I can`t get how to make it work so it takes param "value" as argument.

Example

```
const result = pipe(
  "john_doe",
  replaceUnderscoreWithSpace,
  capitalize,
  appendGreeting,
);
 
alert(result); // Hello, John Doe!
```

Comment: There is RxJS, which would probably do what your trying to do. [Link](https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview)

Comment: @Invizi This looks more like an academic exercise to learn how to write higher-order functions. Using a pre-written tool doesn't teach the basics.

Comment: `pipe("john_doe",` this doesn't seem like a function.

Comment: @VLAZ The first argument to `pipe` is the value to push through the pipeline. The remaining arguments are the pipeline.

Comment: @Barmar not in this implementation `(...funcs) => value =>` EDIT: wait, I guess I misread the code. It's actually `(value, ...funcs) => value =>` - why the two values, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra nested function in your `pipe()` implementation. So `pipe()` returns a function that calls `reduce()` rather than calling `reduce()` itself.

Get rid of `value =>`.

```js
const replaceUnderscoreWithSpace = (value) => value.replace(/_/g, ' ')
const capitalize = (value) =>
    value
        .split(' ')
        .map((val) => val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1))
        .join(' ');
const appendGreeting = (value) => `Hello, ${value}!`

const pipe = (value, ...funcs) => funcs.reduce((value, f) => f(value), value);

const result = pipe(
  "john_doe",
  replaceUnderscoreWithSpace,
  capitalize,
  appendGreeting,
);
 
console.log(result); // Hello, John Doe!
```